# assigning a new array values of another class type

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, polymorphism

Basically I'm trying to make a dynamic array of the derived class which the base class has a composition relationship with another class.

here is the classes I'm using

```
class Album:public PhotoLab{
public:
Album(string);
Album(Image* ,string);
~Album();
void newProject(); //This is the function I'm working on
.
.
private:
string title;
string* names;
};
```

class PhotoLab contains

```
class PhotoLab{
public:
PhotoLab();
PhotoLab(Image*);
PhotoLab(Image*, int);
virtual  ~PhotoLab();
.
.
virtual void newProject()=0;

protected:
Image* I;
int Num;
 virtual void trans()=0;};
```

and the Image Class

```
class Image{
public:
// Image();
 Image(string="");
 ~Image();
.
.

 void load(string);
.
.
private:
 string magicNo;
 int H, W, colorSystem;
 RGB** pixels;
 string ID;};
```

back to class Album where I'm trying to make the dynamic array of I, this is the function I'm using:

```
void Album::newProject(){
 cout<<"Number of images: ";
cin>>Num;
names=new string [Num];
for(int i =0;i<Num;i++){
    cout<<"Image("<<i+1<<") Name: ";
    cin>>names[i];}

    I=new Image[Num];
    for (int i=0;i<Num;i++){
        I[i]=new Image(names[i]);} // I got An error here when I tried to make and object of class Image??
```

what I'm messing here why is that wrong?

Comment: First note: base class should probably have a virtual destructor

Comment: `string* names;` red alert!

Comment: Why the alert? Is it dangerous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function, you are using the variable I, which is an array of Images (you create it that way using new[]). You then get an index into that are, which then has the type Image. Here's the error, you create a new Image using the new operator, but this operator returns an Image*. The compiler cannot convert an Image* to an Image, thus is gives you an error.

The easiest way to solve this would be to declare I as an array of pointers to Images.

```
Image** I;
```

Then create an array of Image pointers in your method as well:

```
I = new Image*[num];
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    I[i] = new Image(names[i]);
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly,, but still I want to know if there is a way to use Image* I and get the same result?

Comment: You could use something similar to: I[i] = Image(names[i]); But note that this will create a temporary object of the class Image, then uses the copy assignment operator to replace the fields, which both isn't efficient and could cause problems when used with dynamically allocated members.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a pointer to a class type.

Try this:

1. Change `Image* I;` in `PhotoLab` to `Image** I;`
2. Change `I=new Image[Num];` in `Album::newProject()` to `I=new Image*[Num];`

Answer (score 0):

Your `I` object is obviously an `Image[]`, i.e. an array of `Image` objects.

When you `new` an `Image`, you will get a *pointer to* an `Image`.  You're trying to set an `Image` (i.e. `I[i]`) to contain an `Image*`.

A word of advice: polymorphic containers should really store some reference type to the actual objects, i.e. an `unique_ptr<Image>` would probably be best.

Another word of advice: don't mess with C-style arrays unless you're (very) experienced or have (lots of) time to debug memory issues.  Use `std::vector` instead:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Image>> I;

for (int i=0; i!=Num; ++i) {
    I.push_back( std::make_unique<Image>(names[i]) );
}
```

BUT!

Possibly you don't even need a polymorphic container `I`: then use a simple `std::vector<Image>`.

```
std::vector<Image> I;

...

for( int i=0; i != Num; ++i) {
    I.emplace_back( names[i] ); // will construct an Image in place
}
```

Comment: I'm not really familiar with vectors can't another way be used?

Comment: You could use another way, but then you're writing C, not C++.  All the allocation/deallocation is solved for you when you use the `vector`.  The C++ standard library is really worth investigating - and it's not that hard at all, if you're prepared to look through the template syntax.